# The law of large numbers and coin flip probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, uncertainty, law-of-large-numbers

I really appreciate some help with the mathematics behind an example I came across:
Suppose a fair coin flip where you are getting a 50% chance for heads. If you want to be 98% certain to make a profit, you would need a sample size of almost 1,900. If you increase the sample size to 5,000, you will theoretically be 99.96% certain to make a profit.

I am not sure how they arrived at the answers: sample size of 1,900 for 98% certainty, and 99.96% certainty for a sample size of 5000. Would someone mind giving some guidance on the mathematics behind that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Xi'an Oh excuse my mistake, I mean a coin with 50% chance Heads and 50% chance Tails, Heads you win $11, Tails you lose $10.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks a lot! I would like to work out the solution myself, would you mind suggesting where I should start to work it out?

Comment: If $X_n$ denotes the gain/loss after $n$ steps you want to approximate $\mathbb P(X_n>0)$ using the CLT.